# Comparación de cadenas sin importar el orden PHP

Tags: php, laravel

Quiero saber si hay una manera de comparar por medio de algún método de PHP, y verificar que dos cadenas sin importar el orden sean iguales,

por ejemplo:

```
$cadena1 = "Pedro Perez";
$cadena2 = "Perez Pedro";
```

Entonces mi pregunta es como puedo hacer que esto me de TRUE en una comparación. Claramente lo hace diferente su orden.

---

Hago esta pregunta porque estoy desarrollando una búsqueda, y quiero que en una comparación de `$cadena1` y `$cadena2` se tomen como un mismo valor, indiferentemente el orden que tengan, siempre y cuando la cadena tenga la mismas palabras

```
public function validName ($searchName, $baseName) {
    $arrayPacsS = explode(" ", $searchName);
    $arrayPacsB = explode(" ", $baseName);

    // $names almacenara el nombre correcto segun el formato Nombre Apellido, en caso de que sea Apellido Nombre
    $names = array();

    foreach($arrayPacsS as $diff)
    {
        foreach($arrayPacsB as $name)
        {
            // Verificamos pronunciación semejantes en el texto, Por ejemplo: Jose debe se igual a Joze o Joce
            if (metaphone($name) == metaphone($diff))
            {
                // Asignamos el valor de pronunciación igual al array correspondiente a la variable $names
                array_push($names, $name);
            }
        }
    }

    // Verificamos quese hayan encontrado coincidecias de propunciaciones iguales
    if (count($names) != 0) 
    {
        // Verificamos la fiferecia
        $result = array_diff($names, $arrayPacsB);

        // Validamos que los nombres sean iguales, si los nombres son iguales retornamos true
        return count($result) == 0 ? $baseName : $searchName;
    }

    // En caso de que no hayan coincidencias de nombre o pronunciación retornamos false
    return $searchName;
}
```

El problema de esto es cuando hago la comparación con cierta cantidad de registros, los resultados se alteran. Por ejemplo cuando hago la comparación con mas de 500 Registros, y considero que el código tampoco es muy optimo.

Comment: deberías agregar lo que has intentado

Comment: una pregunta mas, las cadenas de texto siempre van a tener la misma longitud o eso va a cambiar?

Comment: @Aprendiz Acabo de agregar un código de ejemplo para lo que quiero hacer, Puede que si o puede que no tengan la misma longitud pero eso lo puedo validad en mi código. Pero para hacer esta comparación si seguro deben tener la misma longitud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
//La función convierte las cadenas en array con explode, luego se ordenan
//Y posteriormente se vuelven a convertir en cadena con implode
//Estando ordenadas ya se pueden comparar! Espero te sirva
    <?
    $cadena1="Pedro Perez";
    $cadena2="Perez Pedro";

    if(compara($cadena1,$cadena2)){
        echo "Son iguales<br>";
    }else{
        echo "Son distintas<br>";
    }
    echo "Cadena 1 :".$cadena1."<br>";
    echo "Cadena 2 :".$cadena2."<br>";

    function compara($cadena1,$cadena2){
        $m1 = explode(" ",$cadena1);
        asort($m1);
        $m2 = explode(" ",$cadena2);
        asort($m2); 
        $o1 = implode(" ",$m1);
        $o2 = implode(" ",$m2);
        if($o1==$o2){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Esta solución me gusta bastante para la comparación, ya que lo que necesito es evitar bucles y ciclos For. Etc, realizare las pruebas con tu código, de todas maneras agregue un código de ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer en el post por si quieres ver y aportar alguna idea adicional. gracias

Comment: Cuál es el costo del explode, ordenar y luego hacer join, comparado con los ciclos que usaba el OP?

Answer (score 2):

Yo lo que haría sería utilizar el método `explode()` para crear un `array` con todas las palabras de una de las cadenas y después recorrer el `array` creado para ver si la otra cadena contiene esa palabra.

Esto en código sería así:

```
$cadena1 = "Pedro Perez";
$cadena2 = "Perez Pedro";

$palabras = explode(" ", $cadena1); // ["Pedro", "Perez"]
$comprobar = true;
for($i=0; $i < count($palabras); $i++) 
{
    if(!strpos($cadena2, $palabras[$i] )) // Si la cadena contiene la palabra true, sino false
    {
       $comprobar = false;
    }
}

echo $comprobar;
```

Si quiere podrías meter esto en una función para que te devuelva `true` o `false`.